# How to extract text based on coordinates using PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I want to extract text at the bottom right corner of the PDF using PDFsharp. The only way that is possible is by specifying coordinates.

So, how can I extract text from PDF by specifying coordinates using PDFsharp library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFsharp was not designed for that task. You need third-party code/own code that extracts text along with the co-ordinates.

Maybe you can use PdfTextract to get started:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfTextract/

Comment: Please be aware, `PdfTextract` really is *very* simple and will only work for very simple PDFs. It may serve as a starting point but requires much improvement.

Comment: I have started using PDFBox for the same purpose. Is it a good library for parsing pdfs? Please, note that I am using its .net wrapper.I can't use ItextSharp as it requires user to purchase license.

Answer (score 0):

I used the pdfbox library for the purpose.It is really cumbersome.But it did get the job done.

Comment: While this may be your solution of your problem, it is not an answer to the question "How to extract text based on coordinates using PDFsharp?"

Comment: Point is noted.